# Moving UIView on screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I move UIView on screen up and down like UITableView in iphone? Please explain

Comment: you are talking about `UIScrollView` .. you should read more about the iPhone Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a scroll view. `UIScrollView`, here is a few tutorials on `UIScrollViews`:

[Xcode 4 Tutorial UIScrollView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mws6Zbq_y6c)

[UIScrollView Class Reference Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

[Another Tutorial on UIScrollView](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2010/12/iphone-xcode-create-simple-uiscrollview.html)

The UIScrollView class provides support for displaying content that is larger than the size of the application’s window. It enables users to scroll within that content by making swiping gestures, and to zoom in and back from portions of the content by making pinching gestures.

Comment: to tick press the tick button to make it green!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. If you are looking for exchanging between view positions...like moving one view above another or , say, moving a view that was at top to the bottom & the bottom one to the top, then you might want to look at
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html